# installing numpy for pypy 2.3.5 (python 3.2.5 compatible) on windows 7 with mingw32

Tags: numpy, distutils, pypy

Here is mine small research about how-to install numpy for pypy3 on windows 7 with mingw32 compiler. 
At first,tried to make it simple:

```
pypy setup.py install build --compiler=mingw32
```

But, here i got [this error](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/pypy-issue/2011-July/001040.html). Fortunately, i found [this solution](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/issue/779/). Now, i'm trying again:

```
pypy setup.py install build --compiler=mingw32
```

And the error is:

```
data=DATA_RE.findall(nm_output)
TypeError:can't use a bytes pattern in string-like object
```

This error occurs in file pypy_numpy\numpy\distutils\lib2def.py.
So,the question is about how to handle this?